# Am programming in angularJs what ever data entered in text box it bind till service .JS file but it binding at controller.cs file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

**Cotroller.cs    file code**

```
public string AddCategory(Category category)
        {
            if (category != null)
            {
                category.Active = true;
                db.Categories.Add(category);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return "Category Added";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Invalid Record";
            }
        }
```

**Service.js   file code**

```
this.addCategory = function (category) {
    var response = $http({
        methode: "POST",
        url: "AddCategory",
        data: JSON.stringify(category),
        dateType: "json"

    });
    return response;
}
```

**Controller.js   file code**

```
$scope.AddUpdateCategory = function () {
    var category = {
        CategoryID: $scope.CategoryID,
        CategoryName: $scope.CategoryName,
        BusinessTypeId: $scope.BusinessTypeId,
        CategoryDesc: $scope.CategoryDesc,
        CompanyId: $scope.CompanyId
    };
    var getAction = $scope.Action;

    if (getAction == "Update") {
        category.CategoryID = $scope.CategoryID;
        var getData = angularService.updateCategory(category);
        getData.then(function (msg) {
            //GetAllCategory();
            $('#AddCategoryDiv').hide();
            $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
            swal("Success!", msg.data, "success");

        }, function () {
            sweetAlert("Oops...", "Error in Updating Category!", "error");
        });
    }
    else {
        var getData = angularService.addCategory(category);
        getData.then(function (msg) {
            //GetAllCategory();
            $('#AddCategoryDiv').hide();
            $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
            swal("Success!", msg.data, "success");

        }, function () {
            sweetAlert("Oops...", "Error in Adding Category!", "error");
        });
    }
}
$scope.AddCategoryDiv = function () {
    clearFields();
    $scope.Action = "Add";

}
function clearFields() {
    $scope.CategoryID ="";
    $scope.CategoryName = "";
    $scope.BusinessTypeId = "";
    $scope.CategoryDesc = "";
    $scope.CompanyId = "";
}
```

please suggest solution ,
the data is not updated in database.
what ever data entred in text box that not saved in database.
i need to store the category in database

Comment: So your `catergory` in your Controller.cs is `null`?

Comment: Check with F12 tools the ajax request that gets send. That way you can check if it is a clientside problem or serverside.

Comment: can you post your Category model? also can you please do console.log(category) before your ajax call to AddCategory and post the json, thanks